# How to combine a list in Python with itself?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
L=[['g1','g2'],['g3'],['g4','g5','g6']]
```

now I want

```
L*L=[['g1','g2','g3'],['g1','g2','g4','g5','g6'],['g3','g4','g5','g6']]
```

How do I do it in Python 3.5

Comment: may you add the mssing `'` in the first code block after `g5`? One character edits are not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want two things

- `itertools.combinations(L, 2)` to get all pairs of sublists in your list
- combine each pair to make a new list

To sum up

```
import itertools
LL = [a + b for a, b in itertools.combinations(L, 2)]
```

Comment: itertools did not work man...some kinda name error

Comment: yes it worked...thanx man

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do these in nested for loops

```
l=[[1,2],[3],[4,5,6]]
lxl=[]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(l)):
        lxl.append(l[i]+l[j])
```

lxl would look something like this
`[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6]]`

Comment: it worked...thanx man